# How to get name of stored files in public - laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

When i upload my files to the server, it works fine and displays in my public folder as `img/php786W`. I am currently trying to retrieve my folder but i get file not found on server.

In my controller, `$filename` is returning the original name of the file on the server. So it does not match to be found although it is the same file. 
How can i get this done? I tried to use hashName() but that won't work

**Controller**

```
$file_path = public_path() . '/img/'. $filename;    
if (file_exists($file_path->hashName()))
{
     return Response::download($file_path, $filename, [
     'Content-Length: '. filesize($file_path)
    ]);
}
else
{
    // Error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
return response()->download($pathToFile);
```

If this does not work you have either permissions problem, or the file simply does not exist

See [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#file-downloads)